# React: path__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.join) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I am trying to use `join` function from `path` module inside my React functional component and am getting below error -
`TypeError: (0 , path__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.join) is not a function`

I have referred bunch of answers but they don't seem to be helping my case -

[path join not working in webpack5 but it is working with webpack4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436036/path-join-not-working-in-webpack5-but-it-is-working-with-webpack4)

[TypeError: path.join is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992393/typeerror-path-join-is-not-a-function)

[TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function. How do I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142136/typeerror-react-webpack-imported-module-2-default-is-not-a-function-ho)

[WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13___default(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135245/webpack-imported-module-13-default-is-not-a-function)

[TypeError: util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65624265/typeerror-util-webpack-imported-module-4-default-is-not-a-function)

Here's a sample code -

**File:** hello-component.tsx

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {fetchData} from 'helpers/helpers.ts';

const HelloComponent =  async ({user}) => {
  const user = await fetchData(user);
  // do stuff with useState, useRef, useEffect
  if (isUser) {
    return (<h1>Hello {user}</h1>);
  } else {
    return (<h1> {user} not found!</h1>);
  }
}
```

**File:** helpers/helpers.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {join} from 'path';

export const fetchData = async (user: string) => {
  
  const cfp = join('config', 'configuration.yaml')  // ---> 'join' function causing error 
  const config = readFileSync(cfp, 'utf8');

  // read config using js-yaml module and do stuff...

  const resp = await axios.request({...});
  return resp;
}
```

**File:** package.json

```
{
  // dependencies
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

How do I get rid of the error?

Comment: `path` is an only node.js module I think.

Comment: Thanks @yousoumar, Yes. Also, I went ahead decided to generate and send necessary data as props to the react component.